# 'bizzle' – a curious word - anyone come across it?

Tags: vocabulary

In his memoir *Blessings in Disguise*, Alec Guinness refers to a 'bizzle', evidently meaning a carpet-sweeper. He offers no explanation, as though it were a normal word. I can only guess that it derives from the name of the company Bissell who have made such devices since the 1870s. Has anyone else come across this term?

Comment: Yes. Carpet-sweepers and "Bissell" were synonymous, as they seemed to be made only by that company (and they may have been that company's only product). Are they still in business? Anyway, my grandmother used the term like that. But anecdote is not an answer; hence the comment.

Comment: @AndrewLeach But it **is** an answer: OP asks if anyone has come across the term.

Comment: @StoneyB I've come across the company name but not its being used as an eponym or derived eponym. Should I add this as an answer? Shall lots of people answer 'No'?

Comment: Have you checked in dictionaries? Non-inclusion, plus a lack of non-proper-noun examples on the internet, would strongly suggest that this is not in the lexicon.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It seems to me that what's lurking behind OP's question is whether this use is peculiar to Guinness, and Andrew's saying that his grandmother "used the term like that" addresses that.

Comment: @StoneyB This is the third time today I've given this quote from tchrist: 'We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers.' Giving an 'answer' on ELU lends credibility to the regarding of an expression as being idiomatic. I agree with Andrew Leach that a 'comment' here is the correct approach. I believe it often is. / I'd not label 'bizzle' here as anything more than a 'candidate word'.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Bissell are indeed still in business (https://www.bissell.com/). Perhaps this is a Britishism, rather like the verb "hoover", meaning *to vacuum*.

Comment: @torek I've heard genericised _hoover_ and _ewbank_, but never _bissell/bizzle_. I'd guess Guinness was being inventive (he often was) and using a nonce-word. / There are a few examples of "bisselled the" on the internet, and one or two for "ewbanked the". A few more for "dysoned the". Again, very few for "electroluxed the" and (ignoring false positives) "bosched the".

Comment: @Andrew Leach: When I was a kid we called our mechanical carpet sweeper a ***bex*** - it wasn't until later that we could afford an electric ***hoover***. In both cases I'm sure these were just "generic" names, because we could never have afforded anything made by the actual companies Hoover and Bissel.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that I have checked dictionaries and found no trace of this spelling, which is why I thought I'd try here. Being British myself, I'm familiar with 'to hoover', but Guinness used 'bizzle' as a noun.

Comment: Ah, but Guinness was a master of disguise (these are not the words you're looking for)

Answer (score 2):

Melville Reuben Bissell, (born Sept. 25, 1843, Hartwick, N.Y., U.S.—died March 15, 1889, Grand Rapids, Mich.), U.S. inventor of the carpet sweeper.

You can still buy them today: https://www.bisselldirect.co.uk/sweepers

The expression "gizzle ma bizzle" is Scottish, but I dread to think what that might mean!

Edit: The only dictionary definition of the word "bizzle" I could find came from the Dictionary.University web site: https://dictionary.university/bizzle

bizzle - noun - a buzzing sound made by something sizzling, e.g., a noise coming from the kitchen.

Comment: Yes, I suggested in my question that this was probably the derivation! I was asking whether Alec Guinness's use of that spelling was a one-off.